# Can I offer a bounty for another user's question?

Tags: support, bounties

I wanted to ask a question, but another user had already asked the same 3 hours before.
Now he doesn't get any answer, so I would like to offer a bounty, but I can't ask a duplicate question.
Is there a way to offer a bounty ?

Comment: You can do it in two days, since you have 75 rep.

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't sure it was possible!